# Instantiating an object as class member without default constructor

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++. I want to declare an object as a private member of another class. Is the instantiation of this object can be done with out the default constructor? A sample code is listed here:

```
class Vertex{
  int i;
public: 
  Vertex(int j):i(j){};
  Vertex(const Vertex & v){i=v.i;};
}

class Test{
  Vertex v;
public:
  Test(const Vertex & v1){v(v1);}
}

int main()
{//some code here;
  Vertex v1(int j=1);
  Test(v1); // *error: no matching function for call to 'Vertex::Vertex()'*
  return 0;
}
```

It appears to me once declared an object as a private class member (e.g. Vertex v), the default constructor is immediately sought after. Anyway to avoid this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Vertex v1(int j=1);
> ```

This declares a *function*, `v1`, which returns a `Vertex` and takes an `int` argument. What you want is

```
Vertex v1(1);
```

in addition, you need to use initialiser lists as the other answers have shown:

```
Test(const Vertex & v1) : v(v1) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if the Test class also contains a vector container and I need to push the object v1 into the container during construction of one Test object?

Answer (score 2):

Initialise `Test::v` just as you initialised `Vertex::i`. (It being `private` is entirely irrelevant!)

So, using `Test::Test`'s member initialisation list:

```
Test(const Vertex & v1) : v(v1) {};
```

---

For consistency, then, I would also suggest:

```
Vertex(const Vertex & v) : i(v.i) {};
```

*Initialise* members wherever you can.

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor initialization list:

```
Test(const Vertex & v1) : v(v1) {}
```

Once you're in the constructor's body (between the `{` and `}`), all data members have been initialized. If you don't do it explicitly, they get default initialized, which requires an available default constructor for user defined types.

Next, you are declaring a function here:

```
Vertex v1(int j=1);
```

What you probably meant is

```
Vertex v1(1);
```

Comment: So, is there a single thing wrong with this answer? I wonder, if there is a reason for the down-vote, I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I like the initialization list approach. But if the Test class has more than 1 private member, e.g. the constructor needs to be Test(A a, B b, C c ..., Vertex v1), initialization may not be the best choice.

Comment: @user3348650 It is usually the best choice, and in C++03 it is the only way to initialize data members with user provided constructors. C++11 gives you delegating constructors and initialization at the point of declaration, which make this kind of thing less verbose.